# PHP - make echo permanent and visible to all viewers

Tags: php, html

I am making a simple window, where users can type something into an input form, submit it and it will echo to the screen. However, this echo is only visible to 1 user (the one that submitted the input), and not any other user viewing the site. How could I make the changes made by echo permanent (I can later reset manually), without the need of reload to see the results.

[image]

This is how the page looks. The typed message should display on top white screen to all users (like in chats)

Below is the code I use for my message posting

```
    function postmessage() {
        $message = $_POST['sentmsg'];
        echo "$message<br \>";
    }

    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] == 'POST') {
        postmessage();
    }
```

With this code, there is a problem that the send works only once, but that is not the question's topic.

And the HTML form

```
<form method="post" action="chat.php">
    <input id="textchatfield" type="text" name="sentmsg" value="Mesage here..."/>
    <input id="sendmsg" type="submit" value="Send" name="submit"/>
</form>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want all users to view all messages you will have to save the message in the database which will allow you to display it to everyone, you can delete the messages in the database if you don't want them to be visible anymore, or better yet have groups and the messages posted in these groups get associated to it and only users in that group can see it (assuming there is login functionality)

Edit: 
If you don't want the page to reload, you will have to make use of Ajax requests in order to save the message, and also to retrieve them and display it on the screen. I'm on my phone so can't type an example now sorry

Comment: I started researching about this topic. There is not really a need for a database. But could plausibly a way to do it

Comment: The reason I mentioned a database is because you said you wanted the messages to be permanently, for that to happen you will need to store it somewhere, so a database could help. Although you can't achieve a full chat experience where the chat gets updated for all users with just php, as mentioned by @hurricanedevelopment

Comment: I see. I was just thinking that echo would actually write the output to HTML. But in the case I need history, I will use a database as you mentioned

Answer (score 2):

Impossible with *PHP*.

**PHP** is a serverside language, meaning that it is only run when a user makes a call to the server.  You need to use code that the client runs after they have already made the request to your webpage.  Something like **JavaScript** can accomplish this quite well.

Making changes that take place to multiple users is a bit complicated.  You might want to take a look at sockets and even **nodejs**